# python import a method that depends on a imported class

Tags: python, import

So if I have 2 files that look like this:

File 1

```
import class1
import method1

def method2(something):
    result = method1(classname=class1)
```

File 2

```
def method1(classname):
    some_result = classname.resultfinder
    return some_result
```

Will this work?

I mean, since I am not importing class1 in the file where method1 lives, but method1 still ends up using class1.
Will method1 have access to class1 via the import made in File 1 where method 1 is imported to?

Comment: After writing this I instantly got that feeling "ofcourse it works" but alas, it was already too late. I will now crawl back under my rock and think about the many fine things that can be said about thinking before writing a question on a public board. Many thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should be fine - imagine having to import every possible type that could be passed to a function at runtime.  I don't think a "dynamic" language like that would last very long.

Answer (score 2):

What happened when you tried it?

Note that your import of `method1` is wrong. Apart from that --- yes, you do not need to import everything. Do you think the standard library imports your stuff whenever you use it? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite look right--you don't exactly "import class1", you more import a module (in a file) that *contains* class1, or a module that *contains* method1. So I'd expect to see more like

```
from file2 import method1
from file3 import class1
```

Also, `method1` doesn't so much take a class *name* as a class *object*. Or should that be a class instance object? Sorry if I'm being picky, but hopefully it's educational to consider the distinction.